# Create button inside tableview cell without Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I try to create a button inside the tableview cell without using Interface Builder.
I found this code that I thought it is for creating a button:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(270,10,30,30);
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

}
```

but when I try to run the program nothing show up in the simulator.
am I missing something to create the button with this code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the button to the cell - have you tried

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:button]
```

?

Adjust your button's frame to position it within the contentView and to size the button correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I try the code that you suggested but it did not work.

Comment: It should. Have you tried making everything really simple and just getting one button to show in a cell, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2633603/189804

Answer (score 0):

You have to add code in this method but first of all add custom cell to your table view,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 forwordBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [forwordBtn setTitle:@"Forward" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [forwordBtn addTarget:self 
                   action:@selector(forwordButtonPressed)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    forwordBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10);

    [cell.contentview addSubview:forwordBtn];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your all code in cellforRow At index Datasource method and for add your button on cell you can use this line of code

[cell.contentView addsubview:buttonobject];

button.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,30,30);

And also change Tour button background or style for your conformation it will be there or not.

It will surly work if its working inform us.

Your Welcome.