# UITableView custom accessory button image disappears when tapped

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a UITableView with a custom accessory button created like this:

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method i do the following:

```
  ...
  UIButton *myAccessoryButton =[[[UIButton alloc] init] autorelease];   
  myAccessoryButton =[self makeAccessoryButton: @"arrow2.png"];
 [cell setAccessoryView:myAccessoryButton];
 return cell;
```

and the function `makeAccessoryButton` is defined as follows:

```
- (UIButton *) makeAccessoryButton: (NSString *) imageName
{

UIButton *myAccessoryButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] autorelease];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
myAccessoryButton.frame = frame;
[myAccessoryButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[myAccessoryButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[myAccessoryButton addTarget: self
                      action: @selector(accessoryButtonTapped:withEvent:)
            forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//myAccessoryButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
return ( myAccessoryButton );

}
```

and the function is defined as follows:

```
 - (void) accessoryButtonTapped: (UIControl *) button withEvent: (UIEvent *) event
{   
NSLog(@"testing ...");
}
```

Now the problem is: When I tap on this button, its image will disappear only when the row is highlighted, I tried both states `UIControlStateNormal` and `UIControlStateHighlighted` for that button but the problem still exists, as I mentioned. If I tap that button if the table view row is not selected (or highlighted) there will not be any problem with the button image (it will not disappear). How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I don't think that this is what causes the problem, but is the autorelease message needed in your [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] call?

Comment: @Irene: i put it just to ensure there is no memory leak, but anyway, I removed it, but the problem still exists ...

Comment: I'm trying the same thing and it's not working for me as well. If I add cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone; in cellForRowAtIndexPath then it works, but still I don't understand why..

Comment: @Irene mmm this is so weird I also looked at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633603/selected-uibutton-disappears-inside-selected-uitableviewcell  but it did not work for me as well, please keep me updated if you find any solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Add image for `UIControlStateHighlighted` or `UIControlStateSelected`  in your custom accessory button.

```
[myAccessoryButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but if you read all the question text you will see that I tried all states (normal, highlighted, selected) , but the problem still exists ...

Answer (score 0):

This also drove me mad!

What goes wrong here is that the UIButton inherits the selected state and then it's imageView's selected sate is set wrong.

To fix it, subclass UITableViewCell and overwrite the setSelected method

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if ([self.accessoryView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton*) self.accessoryView;
        [[button imageView] setHighlighted:NO];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are autoreleasing an autoreleased object in this line

```
UIButton *myAccessoryButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] autorelease];
```

While it should be like

```
UIButton *myAccessoryButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Also instead of this code

```
UIButton *myAccessoryButton =[[[UIButton alloc] init] autorelease];   
  myAccessoryButton =[self makeAccessoryButton: @"arrow2.png"];
 [cell setAccessoryView:myAccessoryButton];
 return cell;
```

You can just simple do this

```
 [cell setAccessoryView:[self makeAccessoryButton: @"arrow2.png"]];
 return cell;
```

Try the above suggestion and also set image for all three states

```
[myAccessoryButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

[myAccessoryButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];

[myAccessoryButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
```

Let me know if this works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just set UIButton. Image for all 4 states to same image in IB.

Beware when you select the image from list or type the name make sure to click out of the text field. IB doesnt seem to save the value.

Go back through all 4 states and check image name saved.